# Distance between two 3D point in geodjango (postgis)

Tags: python, django, postgis, postgresql-9.4, geodjango

I have the following problem: 
I created two points, for example:

```
SRID=3857;POINT Z (62780.8532226825 5415035.177460473 100)
SRID=3857;POINT Z (62785.8532226825 5415035.177460473 70)
```

As you can see, there is 5m difference in X coordinates, and 30m in Z coordinates.
When I run `a.distance(b)` in django shell, it returns **5**, which is wrong.

However, whenIi run in a psql shell:

```
SELECT ST_3DDistance(a.coordinates, b.coordinates)
FROM restapi_entityxyz a, restapi_entityxyz b
WHERE a.external_id='6841zef1561' AND b.external_id='1G23Fzd';
```

It returns:

```
st_3ddistance
------------------
 30.4138126514911
```

Which is the correct answer.

Is it a lack of functionality in `geodjango` or a bug? 
Should I use a custom library to perform such a calculation?

My environment is the following:

- Python 3.5,
- Django,
- postgresql 9.4 + postgis
- gdal and a lot of python libraries.

Comment: I am not familiar with geodjango but it sounds like it may be either a bug or lack of functionality. How about using `psycopg2`, `aiopg` or `asyncpg` directly?

Comment: Hey, @GwydionFR I was wondering, did you found my answer helpful?

Comment: Hi @JohnMoutafis, I don't work on this project anymore so I can't relate, but to me there should be a function for this. As a developer I just want to use this kind of calculus without knowing the internal processing, even if it is a simple euclidian distance.

Comment: @GwydionFR it seems strange indeed but I wasn't able to find a ready-made solution to calculate elevation...

Answer (score 1):

The django distance method is not for calculating the distance of 3D points (with elevation) but of 2D.

We can work around that by creating a custom 3d distance calculation method, like the one described here:
[Calculating distance between two points using latitude longitude and altitude (elevation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111529/calculating-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-longitude-and-altitude-e/42394979#42394979)

> - Let:
>    
>     `polar_point_1 = (long_1, lat_1, alt_1)`
>    
>      and 
>      `polar_point_2 = (long_2, lat_2, alt_2)`
> - Translate each point to it's Cartesian equivalent by utilizing this
>     formula:
>
>   ```
>   x = alt * cos(lat) * sin(long)
>   y = alt * sin(lat)
>   z = alt * cos(lat) * cos(long)
>   ```
>
>   and you will have `p_1 = (x_1, y_1, z_1)` and `p_2 = (x_2, y_2, z_2)` points respectively.
> - Finally use the Euclidean formula:
>
>   ```
>   dist = sqrt((x_2-x_1)**2 + (y_2-y_1)**2 + (z_2-z_1)**2)
>   ```

---

*Confirmed solution of a similar issue from the second part of my answer here: [3d distance calculations with GeoDjango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474570/3d-distance-calculations-with-geodjango/43807804#43807804)*