# 3d distance calculations with GeoDjango

Tags: python, django, gis, postgis, geodjango

I am using

- python 2.7.12
- django 1.10.6
- postgreSQL 9.5.6
- postGIS 2.2.2

**First question**

I need to use GeoDjango to calculate distance between two points. When I checked the  [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#distance) it says that *GeoQuerySet.distance()* is deprecated and instead use *Distance()* from *django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions*.

The following code works OK:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance

p1 = Instrument.objects.get(pk=151071000).coordinates
p2 = Instrument.objects.filter(pk=151071008)

for i in p2.annotate(distance=Distance('coordinates', p1)):
    print i.distance
    print i.distance.__class__
```

Output:

```
461.10913945 m
<class 'django.contrib.gis.measure.Distance'>
```

My model:

```
class Instrument(models.Model):
    ...
    coordinates = gis_models.PointField(null=True, blank=True, dim=3)
```

But I have only two points so when I try to use Distance() without *annotate()* it returns instance of class *django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Distance()* rathen than *django.contrib.gis.measure.Distance()*:

```
p1 = Instrument.objects.get(pk=151071000).coordinates
p2 = Instrument.objects.get(pk=151071008).coordinates
print Distance(p1, p2)
```

Output:

```
Distance(Value(SRID=4326;POINT Z (-76.48623600000001 44.260223 0)), GeomValue(SRID=4326;POINT Z (-76.490923 44.262658 0)))
```

How do I receive the same result as with using *annotate()*?

**Second question**

I have to calculate 3d distance that is taking into account depth/elevation. But when I try to do it I receive the same result as with 2d. Below I changed elevation to 200 in the first object:

```
p1 = Instrument.objects.get(pk=151071000)
p1.coordinates = 'SRID=4326;POINT Z (-76.48623600000001 44.260223 200)'
p2 = Instrument.objects.filter(pk=151071008)

for i in p2.annotate(distance=Distance('coordinates', p1.coordinates)):
    print i.distance
```

Output:

```
461.10913945 m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break the problem down:

1. In the [Distance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Distance) class documentation, we can read the following:

   > Accepts two geographic fields or expressions and returns the distance between them, as a **Distance object**.

   So the `Distance(p1, p2)` returns a [`Distance` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/measure/#django.contrib.gis.measure.Distance).
   If you do:

   ```
   p1 = Instrument.objects.get(pk=151071000).coordinates
   p2 = Instrument.objects.get(pk=151071008).coordinates
   d = Distance(m=p1.distance(p2))
   print d.m
   ```

   You will get the measurement in meters.

   I would stick with the `annotate` solution, which seems more solid! (opinionated response)

---

2. `Distance` calculates the 2D distance between two points. In order to get a 3D calculation, you need to create one yourself.
   You can have a look at my method from this question: [Calculating distance between two points using latitude longitude and altitude (elevation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111529/calculating-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-longitude-and-altitude-e/42394979#42394979)

   **EDIT 2019:** Since the initial answer I have composed a Q&A style example here: [How to calculate 3D distance (including altitude) between two points in GeoDjango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618544/how-to-calculate-3d-distance-including-altitude-between-two-points-in-geodjang/45618545#45618545) that uses a far better (and less calculation error-prone) distance calculation between 2 points with altitude.

   *In sort:*

   We need to calculate the 2D [great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) between 2 points using either the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) or the [Vicenty formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) and then we can combine it with the difference (delta) in altitude between the 2 points to calculate the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between them as follows:

   ```
   dist = sqrt(great_circle((lat_1, lon_1), (lat-2, lon_2).m**2, (alt_1 - alt_2)**2)
   ```

   The solution assumes that the altitude is in meters and thus converts the `great_circle`'s result into meters as well.

---

*Leaving this here for comment continuation purposes.*

<s>2. `Distance` calculates the 2D distance between two points. In order to get a 3D calculation, you need to create one yourself. 

You can have a look at my method from this question: [Calculating distance between two points using latitude longitude and altitude (elevation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111529/calculating-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-longitude-and-altitude-e/42394979#42394979)</s>

> - Let polar_point_1 = (long_1, lat_1, alt_1) and polar_point_2 =
>     (long_2, lat_2, alt_2)
> - Translate each point to it's Cartesian equivalent by utilizing this
>     formula:
>
>   ```
>   x = alt * cos(lat) * sin(long)
>   y = alt * sin(lat)
>   z = alt * cos(lat) * cos(long)
>   ```
>
>   and you will have p_1 = (x_1, y_1, z_1) and p_2 = (x_2, y_2, z_2) points respectively.
> - Finally use the Euclidean formula:
>
>   ```
>   dist = sqrt((x_2-x_1)**2 + (y_2-y_1)**2 + (z_2-z_1)**2)
>   ```

Comment: the first piece of code gives me an error *AttributeError: 'Distance' object has no attribute 'm'* because variable *d* is not *django.contrib.gis.measure.Distance* object.

Comment: @Nargiza Because the initial answer didn't work as expected by the docs, I have made this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864292/djangos-distance-function-not-returning-a-distance-object in order to investigate it further!

Comment: Yes, I'm also curious about that!

Answer (score 0):

** python 3.7, Django 2.2.10

some useful functions ive written to help me with lat/lon coordinates in applications

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance


def get_point(lat, lon):
    try:
        lat = float(lat)
        lon = float(lon)
        if lat and lon:
            return Point(x=float(round(lon, 6)), y=float(round(lat, 6)), srid=4326)
        else:
            return None
    except Exception:
        return None


def get_point_to_point_distance(point_one, point_two, measurement_unit="mile"):
    return Distance(**{measurement_unit: point_one.distance(point_two)})
```

where measurement_unit can be any of the following:

```
    STANDARD_UNIT = "m"
    UNITS = {
        'chain': 20.1168,
        'chain_benoit': 20.116782,
        'chain_sears': 20.1167645,
        'british_chain_benoit': 20.1167824944,
        'british_chain_sears': 20.1167651216,
        'british_chain_sears_truncated': 20.116756,
        'cm': 0.01,
        'british_ft': 0.304799471539,
        'british_yd': 0.914398414616,
        'clarke_ft': 0.3047972654,
        'clarke_link': 0.201166195164,
        'fathom': 1.8288,
        'ft': 0.3048,
        'german_m': 1.0000135965,
        'gold_coast_ft': 0.304799710181508,
        'indian_yd': 0.914398530744,
        'inch': 0.0254,
        'km': 1000.0,
        'link': 0.201168,
        'link_benoit': 0.20116782,
        'link_sears': 0.20116765,
        'm': 1.0,
        'mi': 1609.344,
        'mm': 0.001,
        'nm': 1852.0,
        'nm_uk': 1853.184,
        'rod': 5.0292,
        'sears_yd': 0.91439841,
        'survey_ft': 0.304800609601,
        'um': 0.000001,
        'yd': 0.9144,
    }

    # Unit aliases for `UNIT` terms encountered in Spatial Reference WKT.
    ALIAS = {
        'centimeter': 'cm',
        'foot': 'ft',
        'inches': 'inch',
        'kilometer': 'km',
        'kilometre': 'km',
        'meter': 'm',
        'metre': 'm',
        'micrometer': 'um',
        'micrometre': 'um',
        'millimeter': 'mm',
        'millimetre': 'mm',
        'mile': 'mi',
        'yard': 'yd',
        'British chain (Benoit 1895 B)': 'british_chain_benoit',
        'British chain (Sears 1922)': 'british_chain_sears',
        'British chain (Sears 1922 truncated)': 'british_chain_sears_truncated',
        'British foot (Sears 1922)': 'british_ft',
        'British foot': 'british_ft',
        'British yard (Sears 1922)': 'british_yd',
        'British yard': 'british_yd',
        "Clarke's Foot": 'clarke_ft',
        "Clarke's link": 'clarke_link',
        'Chain (Benoit)': 'chain_benoit',
        'Chain (Sears)': 'chain_sears',
        'Foot (International)': 'ft',
        'German legal metre': 'german_m',
        'Gold Coast foot': 'gold_coast_ft',
        'Indian yard': 'indian_yd',
        'Link (Benoit)': 'link_benoit',
        'Link (Sears)': 'link_sears',
        'Nautical Mile': 'nm',
        'Nautical Mile (UK)': 'nm_uk',
        'US survey foot': 'survey_ft',
        'U.S. Foot': 'survey_ft',
        'Yard (Indian)': 'indian_yd',
        'Yard (Sears)': 'sears_yd'
    }
```