# Django's Distance function not returning a Distance object

Tags: python, django, geodjango

This is an unexpected behavior that came up on the road to solve this problem with @Nargiza: [3d distance calculations with GeoDjango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474570/3d-distance-calculations-with-geodjango/43807804#43807804).

Following the Django docs on the [Distance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Distance) **function**:

> Accepts two geographic fields or expressions and **returns the distance between them, as a Distance object**.

And from a [Distance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/measure/#django.contrib.gis.measure.Distance) **object**, we can get the distance in each and every one of the [supported units](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/measure/#supported-units).

**But:**

Let model be:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    coordinates = models.PointField()
```

then the following:

```
p1 = MyModel.objects.get(id=1).coordinates
p2 = MyModel.objects.get(id=2).coordinates
d = Distance(p1, p2) # This is the function call, 
                     # so d should be a Distance object
print d.m
```

should print the distance between `p1` and `p2` in meters.

Instead, we got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Distance' object has no attribute 'm'
```

We found a workaround eventually (`d = Distance(m=p1.distance(p2))`) but the question remains:

Why the `Distance` **function** didn't return a `Distance` **object**?
Is this a bug, or we missed something?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those two aren't that closely related to each other. Docs do indeed say that it "returns" Distance object, but there is an extra step:

*django.contrib.gis.**db.models**.functions.Distance* is a *database* function, it takes two expressions (that may include database field names) and returns a  [Func](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) object that can be used as a part of a query.

So simply put, it needs to be executed in a database. It will calculate distance using database function (e.g. [postgis ST_Distance](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance.html)) and then bring it back as a *django.contrib.gis.measure.Distance* object.

So, unless one wants to mess with SQL compilers and db connections, easiest way to get Distance between two points is `Distance(m=p1.distance(p2))`

**EDIT:** Some code to illustrate the point:

You can check out code for Distance (measurement) class in [django/contrib/gis/measure.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/measure.py). It's fairly small and easy to understand. All it's doing is giving you a convenient way to do conversion, comparison and arithmetic operations with distances:

```
In [1]: from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance

In [2]: d1 = Distance(mi=10)

In [3]: d2 = Distance(km=15)

In [4]: d1 > d2
Out[4]: True

In [5]: d1 + d2
Out[5]: Distance(mi=19.32056788356001)

In [6]: _.km
Out[6]: 31.09344
```

Now, let's take a look at the Distance function:

Add `__str__` method to the model so we can see distance value when it returned by the queryset api and short db_table name so we can look in the queries:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    coordinates = models.PointField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'mymodel'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.coordinates} {getattr(self, 'distance', '')}"
```

Create some objects and do a simple `select * from` query:

```
In [7]: from gisexperiments.models import MyModel

In [8]: from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

In [10]: some_places = MyModel.objects.bulk_create(
    ...:     MyModel(coordinates=Point(i, i, srid=4326)) for i in range(1, 5)
    ...: )

In [11]: MyModel.objects.all()
Out[11]: <QuerySet [<MyModel: SRID=4326;POINT (1 1) >, <MyModel: SRID=4326;POINT (2 2) >, <MyModel: SRID=4326;POINT (3 3) >, <MyModel: SRID=4326;POINT (4 4) >]>

In [12]: str(MyModel.objects.all().query)
Out[12]: 'SELECT "mymodel"."id", "mymodel"."coordinates" FROM "mymodel"'
```

Boring. Let's use Distance function to add distance value to the result:

```
In [14]: from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance

In [15]: from django.contrib.gis.measure import D  # an alias

In [16]: q = MyModel.objects.annotate(dist=Distance('coordinates', origin))

In [17]: list(q)
Out[17]:
[<MyModel: SRID=4326;POINT (1 1) 157249.597768505 m>,
 <MyModel: SRID=4326;POINT (2 2) 314475.238061007 m>,
 <MyModel: SRID=4326;POINT (3 3) 471652.937856715 m>,
 <MyModel: SRID=4326;POINT (4 4) 628758.663018087 m>]

In [18]: str(q.query)
Out[18]: 'SELECT "mymodel"."id", "mymodel"."coordinates", ST_distance_sphere("mymodel"."coordinates", ST_GeomFromEWKB(\'\\001\\001\\000\\000 \\346\\020\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\'::bytea)) AS "distance" FROM "mymodel"'
```

You can see it uses `ST_distance_sphere` sql function do calculate distance using values from `"mymodel"."coordinates"` and byte representation of our `origin` point.

We can now use it for filtering and ordering and lots of other things, all inside the database management system (fast):

```
In [19]: q = q.filter(distance__lt=D(km=400).m)

In [20]: list(q)
Out[20]:
[<MyModel: SRID=4326;POINT (1 1) 157249.597768505 m>,
 <MyModel: SRID=4326;POINT (2 2) 314475.238061007 m>]
```

Notice `.m` you need to pass float number to the filter, it won't be able to recognize Distance object.

Comment: Let me know if I need to add some code to the answer. I wanted to but struggled to get something minimal. I'll try again later

Comment: Thank you for the response @Igonato , if you can provide a code sample that would be nice! I will keep the bounty up in case of other responses :)

Comment: @JohnMoutafis added some code. I'm quite new to GeoDjango, maybe there is a better way to explain it, but this is my best. Also, fixed an error. Function Distance returns Func, not a Lookup object