# Django django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Distance to return values in feet instead of meters

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-orm

The following code will filter properly:

```
def nearby(self, latitude, longitude, proximity=None):
        """Get nearby Merchants.

        Custom queryset method for getting merchants associated with
        nearby places.

        Returns:
            A queryset of ``Merchant`` objects.

        """
        point = Point(latitude, longitude)

        # we query for location nearby for places first and then
        # annotate with distance to the same place
        return self.filter(
            places__location__distance_lte=(point, D(ft=proximity))
        ).annotate(distance=models.Min(Distance('places__location', point)))
```

but the value returned by

```
models.Min(Distance('places__location', point))
```

is in meters.

Is it possible to get it in feet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take a look at the [`Distance` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Distance) we will see this:

> Because the distance attribute is a Distance object, you can easily express the value in the units of your choice.

Although this is not [entirely true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864292/djangos-distance-function-not-returning-a-distance-object):

> Those two aren't that closely related to each other. Docs do indeed say that   it "returns" Distance object, but there is an extra step:
>
> `django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Distance` is a database function, it takes two expressions (that may include database field names) and returns a `Func` object that can be used as a part of a query.
>
> So simply put, it needs to be executed in a database. It will calculate distance using database function (e.g. postgis ST_Distance) and then bring it back as a `django.contrib.gis.measure.Distance` object

---

Judging from the above you can do:

```
... .annotate(distance=models.Min(Distance('places__location', point).ft))
```