# GeoDjango how to display distance in meters in this query

Tags: python, django, distance, geo, geodjango

GeoDjango how to display distance in meters in this query

Right now I'm just displaying them by distance ranking.

I would like to get the distance in meters more

models.py

```
class Master(models.Model):
    city_master = models.ForeignKey(myCity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="cityName", db_index=True, related_name="CityName_relate")
    country_master = models.ForeignKey(CountryMy, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="countryName", db_index=True, related_name="CountryMyName_relate")
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=3000)
    point = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance

class MainList(View):
.....

    def get(self, request):
   ........

        current_location = BaseUrl.objects.get(Country__nameCountry_for_sites=str(country)).point

        main_masters_in_country = myCity.objects.filter(
            point__distance_lte=((current_location, D(km=50)))).annotate(
            distance=Distance('point', current_location)).order_by('distance')[:5]



       return render(request, self.template_name, context={'main_masters_in_country': main_masters_in_country}, )
```

I would like to get the distance in meters more

Thanks friends/謝謝朋友/Gracias amigos/Danke Freunde/Merci les amis/धन्यवाद दोस्तों/Спасибо друзья

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar (but not direct duplicate it believe) to this question: [Django django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Distance to return values in feet instead of meters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424848/django-django-contrib-gis-db-models-functions-distance-to-return-values-in-feet)

Django's [`Distance` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Distance) state the following:

> Because the distance attribute is a `Distance` object, you can easily express the value in the units of your choice. For example, `city.distance.mi` is the distance value in miles and `city.distance.km` is the distance value in kilometers. See Measurement Objects for usage details and the list of Supported units.
> quote

Therefore, in order to express the distance in meters you can modify the query as follows:

```
(...).annotate(
    distance=Distance('point', current_location).m
).order_by('distance')[:5]
```