# How convert miles km in geodjango

Tags: python, django, geolocation, geodjango, geopy

I have this view that works fine but I am finding difficult to display the result in km. I calculated the distance between two points but I get the results in meters but I want it in kilometers.

```
vews.py

from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance



class SearchResultsView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "search.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get('q', default='')
        location_ = self.request.GET.get('location')
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geo", timeout=10000)
        location = geolocator.geocode(location_)
        print(location)
        new = Point(location.latitude, location.longitude, srid=4326)
        context.update({
            'job_listing': JobListing.objects.annotate(
                distance=Distance("location_on_the_map", new)
            ).filter(Q(job_title__icontains=query)).order_by("distance")
        })
        return context
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Distance to return values in feet instead of meters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424848/django-django-contrib-gis-db-models-functions-distance-to-return-values-in-feet)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [geodjango docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#distance)  the Distance object you are annotating into your JobListing queryset will do the conversion for you - you just need to refer to distance.km or distance.mi