# How to calculate 3D distance (including altitude) between two points in GeoDjango

Tags: python, django, gis, postgis, geodjango

**Prologue:**

This is a question arising often in SO:

- [3d distance calculations with GeoDjango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474570/3d-distance-calculations-with-geodjango/43807804#43807804)
- [Calculating distance between two points using latitude longitude and altitude (elevation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111529/calculating-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-longitude-and-altitude-e/42394979#42394979)
- [Distance between two 3D point in geodjango (postgis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024322/distance-between-two-3d-point-in-geodjango-postgis/42644003#42644003)

I wanted to compose an example on SO Documentation but the `geodjango` chapter never took off and since the Documentation got shut down on August 8, 2017, I will follow the suggestion of [this widely upvoted and discussed meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation/354302#354302) and write my example as a self-answered post.

Of course, I would be more than happy to see any different approach as well!!

---

**Question:**

Assume the model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    coordinates = models.PointField()
```

Where I store the point in the `coordinate` variable as a `lan, lng, alt` point:

```
MyModel.objects.create(
    name='point_name', 
    coordinates='SRID=3857;POINT Z (100.00 10.00 150)')
```

I am trying to calculate the 3D distance between two such points:

```
p1 = MyModel.objects.get(name='point_1').coordinates
p2 = MyModel.objects.get(name='point_2').coordinates

d = Distance(m=p1.distance(p2))
```

Now `d=X` in meters.

If I change only the altitude of one of the points in question:

For example:

```
p1.coordinates = 'SRID=3857;POINT Z (100.00 10.00 200)'
```

from 150 previously, the calculation:

```
d = Distance(m=p1.distance(p2))
```

returns `d=X` again, like the elevation is ignored.
How can I calculate the 3D distance between my points?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading from the documentation on the [`GEOSGeometry.distance`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/geos) method:

> Returns the distance between the closest points on this geometry and the given geom (another GEOSGeometry object).
>
> Note
>
> **GEOS distance calculations are linear** – in other words, GEOS does not perform a spherical calculation even if the SRID specifies a geographic coordinate system.

Therefore we need to implement a method to calculate a more accurate 2D distance between 2 points and then we can try to apply the altitude (Z) difference between those points.

**1. Great-Circle 2D distance calculation *(Take a look at the 2022 UPDATE below the explanation for a better approach using `geopy`)***:

The most common way to calculate the distance between 2 points on the surface of a sphere (as the Earth is simplistically but usually modeled) is the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula):

> The haversine formula determines the [great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) between two points on a sphere given their longitudes and latitudes.

Although from the [great-circle distance wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) we read:

> Although this formula is accurate for most distances on a sphere, it too suffers from rounding errors for the special (and somewhat unusual) case of antipodal points (on opposite ends of the sphere). A formula that is accurate for all distances is the following special case of the [Vincenty formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) for an ellipsoid with equal major and minor axes.

We can create our own implementation of the Haversine or the Vincenty formula (as shown here for Haversine: [Haversine Formula in Python (Bearing and Distance between two GPS points)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points/4913653#4913653)) or we can use one of the already implemented methods contained in [geopy](https://github.com/geopy/geopy):

- [`geopy.distance.great_circle`](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#geopy.distance.great_circle) (Haversine):

  ```
      from geopy.distance import great_circle
      newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796)
      cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391)

      # This call will result in 536.997990696 miles
      great_circle(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles)
  ```
- [`geopy.distance.vincenty`](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#geopy.distance.vincenty) (Vincenty):

  ```
      from geopy.distance import vincenty
      newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796)
      cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391)

      # This call will result in 536.997990696 miles
      vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles
  ```

**!!!2022 UPDATE: On 2D distance calculation using `geopy`:**

`GeoPy` discourages the use of `Vincenty` as of version 1.14.0. [Changelog](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog_1xx.html?highlight=vincenty#id11) states:

> CHANGED: Vincenty usage now issues a warning. Geodesic should be used instead. Vincenty is planned to be removed in geopy 2.0. (#293)

So (especially if we are going to apply the calculation on a WGS84 ellipsoid) we should use [`geodesic` distance instead](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html?highlight=geodesic#geopy.distance.geodesic):

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic
newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796)
cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391)

# This call will result in 538.390445368 miles
geodesic(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles
```

**2. Adding altitude to the mix:**

As mentioned, each of the above calculations yields a great circle distance between 2 points. That distance is also called "as the crow flies", assuming that the "crow" flies without changing altitude and as straight as possible from point A to point B.

We can have a better estimation of the "walking/driving" ("as the crow walks"??) distance by combining the result of one of the previous methods with the difference (delta) in altitude between point A and point B, inside the [Euclidean Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) for distance calculation:

```
acw_dist = sqrt(great_circle(p1, p2).m**2 + (p1.z - p2.z)**2)
```

---

**The previous solution is prone to errors especially the longer the real distance between the points is. 
*I leave it here for comment continuation reasons.***

<s>GeoDjango `Distance` calculates the 2D distance between two points and doesn't take into consideration the altitude differences.

In order to get the 3D calculation, we need to create a distance function that will consider altitude differences in the calculation:</s>

**Theory:**

The `latitude`, `longitude` and `altitude` are [Polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) and we need to translate them to [Cartesian coordinates (`x`, `y`, `z`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) in order to apply the [Euclidean Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) on them and calculate their 3D distance.

- Assume: 
  `polar_point_1 = (long_1, lat_1, alt_1)` 
  and 
   `polar_point_2 = (long_2, lat_2, alt_2)`
- Translate each point to it's Cartesian equivalent by utilizing this formula:

  ```
   x = alt * cos(lat) * sin(long)
   y = alt * sin(lat)
   z = alt * cos(lat) * cos(long)
  ```

and you will have `p_1 = (x_1, y_1, z_1)` and `p_2 = (x_2, y_2, z_2)` points respectively.

- Finally use the Euclidean formula:

  ```
   dist = sqrt((x_2-x_1)**2 + (y_2-y_1)**2 + (z_2-z_1)**2)
  ```

Comment: The line which represents the distance calculated here possibly crosses the interior of the Earth (for instance, a point in Japan and another one in United States). Doesn't this generate inaccurate answers? Calculating the great-circle distance using the haversine formula is more accurate (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

Comment: @AlanEvangelista You are right. Your comment pushed me in the right direction to find a less erroneous solution. Have a look at the edited answer :)

Comment: `sqrt(great_circle(p1, p2).m**2, (p1.z - p2.z)**2)` should be `sqrt(great_circle(p1, p2).m**2 + (p1.z - p2.z)**2)` no? replace comma with +?

Comment: @Krupip good catch, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using `geopy`, this is the easiest and perfect solution.

https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.distance.lonlat

```
>>> from geopy.distance import distance
>>> from geopy.point import Point
>>> a = Point(-71.312796, 41.49008, 0)
>>> b = Point(-81.695391, 41.499498, 0)
>>> print(distance(a, b).miles)
538.3904453677203
```

Comment: geopy's distance function is using WGS-84 ellipsoid by default, which is the most globally accurate. https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.distance
I can't understand @John Moutafis who downvoted my answer.

Comment: If you run this and use anything other than "0" for alt, you will get `ValueError: Calculating distance between points with different altitudes is not supported`

Answer (score -1):

Once converted into Cartesian coordinates, you can compute the norm with numpy:

```
np.linalg.norm(point_1 - point_2)
```