# Why is nothing being saved when trying to update geoDjango Point objects?

Tags: python, django, google-maps-api-3, gis, geodjango

---

**SOLVED**: see my own answer for an explanation.

---

I am writing an API to help me maintain my database when needed.

One function of my API is for updating a specific geoDjango `Point` field of all the concerned objects, thanks to a dedicated method of my model (which is pretty useless rergading to *EDIT 1*, see below).

The issue I have been facing with is the following: nothing seems to be saved to the database when calling that method on several objects, even if a call to `save` method seems to work while browsing the objects.

See *EDIT 2*, I figured out this issue was specific to geoDjango `Point` objects (everything else is being updated as expected).

Here below is my model:

#### models.py

```
class Location(geoModels.Model):
    coord_field = geoModels.PointField(blank=True, null=True)
    valTest = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="tagada") # only used to understand why coord_field can't be updated properly
    def update_coord_field(self):
        # some stuff is being done
        self.coord_field = Point(
            newLong,
            newLat,
            srid=3857 # I am trying to update that value
        )
        # nothing more
```

`newLong` and `newLat` are being generated thanks to Google Maps API.
As Google Maps seems to be working with `SRID 3857` while GeoDjango uses `SRID 4326` by default when creating a new `Point`, I want to force SRID of `self.coord_field` to `SRID 3857` (I have been facing incoherent distance calculus, so I am trying to play with SRID to solve that).

Now here is my script :

#### script.py

```
from MyApp import models as MyAppModels
def update_all_coord_field():
    for location in MyAppModels.Location.objects.all():
        print("  old SRID : ", location.coord_field.srid)
        location.update_coord_field()
        location.save()
        print("  new SRID : ", location.coord_field.srid)
update_all_coord_field()
```

But when trying to execute my script again (or simply just trying to use my new valued attribute), I can only observe that nothing was saved to the db (it still `print` the old value of `location.coord_field.srid` for all `Location`objects).

How my script is being executed:

```
python manage.py shell
exec(script.py)
```

If I call twice my script, here is the following traceback (only one object to make thinks understandable):

```
exec(script.py)
  old SRID : 4326
  new SRID : 3857 # so apparently object has been updated...
exec(script.py)
  old SRID: 4326 # ...but this line proves that the updated value has not been pushed to the database
  new SRID: 3857
```

**Do you have any idea why is this not working?**

---

**FIRST EDIT**: @JohnMoutafis pointed out to me there was already a function to change `SRID` of `Point` objects: `transform`.

```
Location.objects.get(pk=pk).transform(3857) # define a new value of SRID
```

It is usefull, yet it does not solve my issue! Please notice I did not update my code here with that `transform` method.

---

**SECOND EDIT**: I've been through a lot of pain to understand that it is **not** the `save` method which is not working! Actually, if I try to update "casual" data field of `MyAppModel`, everything works fine and is updated as expected. The real issue is only about my `coord_field` attribute which **can't** be updated, and I can't figure out why.

In my script I tried on the one hand what I explained above, and on the other hand I also tried the following to update manually (and not through a custom method of my model) `coord_field`:

```
MyAppModels.Location.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(
    geoCoord=Point(location.geoCoord.x, location.geoCoord.y, srid=3857),
    valTest="meat"
)
```

As a result, if I execute again my script, I see that `valTest` has been properly updated (nice!), but `geoCoord` still is the old value! :-( With the wrong SRID and everything. So, I think I really have a trouble updating `geoDjango Point object` in particular, and will update the title of my question as a consequence of that!

Comment: Please show the exact code that is not working. I'm not sure that you've shown enough to show what the problem is.

Comment: Where do `newLong`, `newLat`, `newSRID` etc come from? How are you verifying that nothing changes?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, and sorry @Sayse I was editing my post while you were writing your comment! What I really want to change is the srid of my points. This is what I'm trying to display through my script to check if this value has effectively being updated. newLong, newLat are being computed by GoogleMaps API, but newSRID is specified manually (I want the same as for Gmaps, meaning 3857, against geoDjango default which is 4326). The purpose of that is to find out why the distance calculus through django is not coherent with googlemaps's one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**: my conlusion is that once you specified `SRID` of one `Point`, you can not change it later. Even the `transform` method won't change `SRID`, but will only make some conversion *in place*, without altering original `SRID` of your `Point`. Actually, I think that when I write:

```
coord_field = geoModels.PointField(blank=True, null=True)
```

the default 4826 `SRID` is already set once for all to the appropriate column of the database (and only this `SRID` can then be used for this column). So, even when I write:

```
self.coord_field = Point(newLong, newLat, srid=newSRID)
```

I won't be able to associate another `SRID` to my Point. Some calculus is going to be computed, but at the end the `Point` attribute will still be affected of the initial `SRID`.

To be clear: I am not sure 100% about those conclusions (I did not find any appropriate doc), but deleting `coord_field` column then setting `coord_field` as follows:

```
coord_field = geoModels.PointField(srid=3857, blank=True, null=True)
```

..did the trick. If anyone has got some clean answer for me, I would still appreciate to read it!

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [gis.stackexchange post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94640/geodjango-transform-not-working?answertab=votes#tab-top), I will assume that you are declaring each point initially without an explicit `srid`, therefore GeoDajngo assumes that you must have declared it on 4326.

1. You need to declare every point in your database explicitly.
   Here is a script to help you do that with your existing points.

   ```
   for item in Location.objects.all():
       item.coord_field = Point(item.coord_field.x, item.coord_field.y, srid=4326)
       item.save()
   ```
2. You can use [`transform`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.transform) instead of your custom method to change the `srid` of your Points:

   ```
   Location.objects.all().transform(3857)
   ```

**EDIT due to comment:**

Since clarification provided by @KrazyMax on the comments, he needs to calculate the spherical distance. I have made a post about that here: [How to calculate 3D distance (including altitude) between two points in GeoDjango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618544/how-to-calculate-3d-distance-including-altitude-between-two-points-in-geodjang)

Comment: `transform` method is a nice thing I was not aware about! Even if it does not answer my question, thanks for the tip, I am definitely going to use that instead of my custom function. Anyway, I think I am getting uncoherent distance calculus because of the [following geoDjango doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.distance) : 

> _GEOS distance calculations are linear – in other words, GEOS does not perform a spherical calculation even if the SRID specifies a geographic coordinate system._

Comment: @KrazyMax I was under the assumption that your srid didn't get updated... I will add a link that will help you.

Comment: Well there are 2 things: SRID is actually **not** being updated to the database (`Point` objects already exist, but their SRID are not modified afterwards). Then, I am not especially trying to calculate distance with `Point` having an elevation (working in 2D would be just fine). My issue is that even if `lat` and `long` for `PointA` and `PointB` are defined within Gmaps API, `PointA.distance(PointB)` returns something slightely different from what I get on Gmaps website: 459km against 388km in real! So, still investigating for that weird result... Will give some try tonight to your calc func!