# Geopy geopy.distance ignoring altitude specification?

Tags: python, distance, geopy, altitude

I'm trying to calculate distance between 2 locations. Each location has `lat, lon, altitude`. 
When calculating distance using `Geopy` it doesn't seem to consider the altitude:
slight changes in `lat, lot` influence the result, small/huge change in altitude doesn't affect the resulting distance.
What am I doing wrong? How to calculate geo distance considering the altitude?
Thanks!

```
import geopy

p1 = geopy.point.Point()
p1.latitude = 10
p1.longitude = -110

p2 = geopy.point.Point()
p2.altitude = 35
p2.latitude = 20
p2.longitude = -120

# low alt
p1.altitude = 350 
print(geopy.distance.geodesic(p1, p2).km)
# 1541.8564339502925

# high alt
p1.altitude = 3500000 
print(geopy.distance.geodesic(p1, p2).km)
# 1541.8564339502925
```

Comment: seems like `geopy.distance.geodesic` is indeed ignoring the specified altitude. As a workaround, you could add the calculation of the Euclidean distance as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42394979/10197418).

Comment: thanks! euclidean distance isn't good enough for this task. eventually i have wrote a learning based algorithm that considers altitude as well.

Comment: Maybe open an issue on the [geopy github page](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/issues)? I think the option to include altitude information can lead to the false assumption that this would be included in the distance calculation - despite the fact that there's not only one way to include it in the calculation... So this should at least be clarified in the docs.

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/geopy/geopy/issues/387